# With 2 sets of strings, find a string that can be constructed from either set

Tags: java, string

Given the following sets of strings:

```
are yo
you u
how nhoware
alan arala
dear de
```

I need to find a sequence that can be constructed by concatenating the strings in either columnm, and it must use the same number of elements in both cases.

For example, **"dearalanhowareyou"** can be constructed from both sets of strings, using 5 elements each time.

A invalid choice would be **"dearalanhoware"** since it would use 4 elements from the left column but only 3 from the right

The problem is taken from here:

https://open.kattis.com/problems/correspondence

I'm using this site to improve for future job interviews and I just can't seem to figure this one out at all.

My only working implementation is a brute force approach taking every possible combination of each set which is not a very good solution due to time complexity.

My code right now:

```
list1 = getPermutations("",send1);
        list2 = getPermutations("",send2);

 ArrayList<String> duplicateValues = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            if (list2.contains(list1.get(i))) {
                duplicateValues.add(list1.get(i));
            }

private static ArrayList<String> getPermutations(String currentResult, ArrayList<String> possibleChars) {
        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>(possibleChars.size());
        for (String append : possibleChars) {
            String permutation = currentResult + append; 



            result.add(permutation); 
            if (possibleChars.size() > 0) {

                ArrayList<String> possibleCharsUpdated = (ArrayList) possibleChars.clone();

                possibleCharsUpdated.remove(new String(append));

                result.addAll(getPermutations(permutation, possibleCharsUpdated));
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Before asking here, at least try some code. We won't write your program for you, if that's what you're asking us to do.

Comment: I wrote an implementation to brute force it, taking every single possible combination of both sets and comparing them, which is only really feasible for small sets. I can't seem to figure out a different way of doing it

Comment: Does it work as expected? What's wrong with it?

Comment: It works, however it is dreadfully slow, when provided with a test case with 8 strings in each sets it takes well over 15 seconds to run

Comment: Maybe provide the code on Codereview (a branch of SO). This would probably fit better there, rather than on a basic question.

Comment: I just think you'd get more help there. It's better fit to help you in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can significantly narrow down the amount of permutations that you need to check by finding which words from each set could possibly begin the constructed String. In this case, the only two choices are *dear* and *de* because *de* is a substring of *dear*. Once you get the String started you can take a substring of the longer String, in this case `"dear".substring("de".length())` returns *ar* which tells you that the next element from the right side needs to start with *ar*. So basically you have two cases :

```
String stringLeft = "", stringRight = "";

if(stringLeft.length() == stringRight.length())
{
    //find two matching Strings here (one is substring of another)
    String[] matching = getMatching(); //returns 1d array of size 2(if only two strings match)
    stringLeft += matching[0];
    stringRight += matching[1];
}
else
{
    if(stringLeft.length() > stringRight.length())
    {
        String start = stringLeft.substring(stringRight.length());
        //find string on right that starts with start
        stringRight += getStringStartingWith(start);
    }
    else
    {
        String start = stringRight.substring(stringLeft.length());
        //find string on left that starts with start
        stringLeft += getStringStartingWith(start);
    }
}
```

The only thing you need to look out for is if there are multiple matching Strings, or Strings starting with the substring you're looking for.